# cognos error:The request was cancelled by the user.....how to solve without restarting the server

Tags: cognos

When I try to run a report in cognos 10.1, i always get the error:
XQE error encountered: The request was cancelled by the user.

The error goes away when we restart cognos server. Is there any other way of solving the issue since restarting so many times is a problem.

Comment: This is very generic question.
You should consider using IBM support for this problem, as it can happen due to many reasons (memory, configuration, report/s issue, fix pack installation/s and many other reasons....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me if I run a report, cancel it, then run the same report again. This is due to 'high affinity' getting confused and trying to reuse an process that has been cancelled.

When I run the report for a third time it's fine.

Does it only happen for a single report, all reports, some reports? How exactly do you reproduce the problem?

If restarting the server is an issue you could just install two app servers and restart them one at a time, and your users will experience no down time at all.

I don't think you will be able to solve it here but we can at least get you to think about stating your issue more clearly.

Comment: Thanks. But it keeps happening  for me on 3rd, 4th and subsequent attempts. On any report on the server. It is like once I have cancelled execution on one report, I cannot run any report at all.

Comment: If you are in a position to reconfigure the server, you could try temporarily setting 0 high affinity connections and only having low affinity instead. I suggest you try this to see if it removes the problem. However this is not a long term solution. You also need to consider why you are cancelling reports so much?